# Increase key buffer (for ungetch)

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

In my curses program, I sometimes need to use `ungetch` to put back a lot of characters at once. However, there is a limit:

```
foreach my $character (reverse split('', "put back this string")) {
  ungetch($character);
}
```

For a large string though, `ungetch` fails (it returns -1, which I should check for above). How can I increase the buffer or limit that controls how many letters I must push back before I have to do a `getch`?

Answer (score 4):

The size of the buffer is provided by the underlying curses library that the Perl curses implementation. In ncurses the input queue size is defined at [ncurses/curses.priv.h](https://github.com/enthought/ncurses-5.5/blob/master/ncurses/curses.priv.h) , where it is defined as FIFO_SIZE is MAXCOLUMNS+2, which is 137 for the newer versions of ncurses.

In order to increase the input queue size, you would need to increase that value and recompile your system's curses implementation.

The underlying method which clears the input queue `fifo_clear` isn't exposed outside of the curses implementation source code, which means it is not provided to the Perl binding. The only provided method I am aware of is getch, which you already specify as a workaround.